# jQuery DataTables - fix columns width with and without scrollbar

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been searching for the answer for hours now and I can't seem to find the answer. I'm developind an intranet web app with asp.net mvc. On the homepage there are two tables for which we are using jQuery DataTables. The data is acquired via ajax and number of rows changes a lot.

Our users complain that tables resize depending on whether the scrollbar is present or not, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMuBb.png).

I've tried everything I can think of. I almost succeded with manually resizing elements after every redraw but whatever worked on Chrome didn't work on IE11 (default browser in the company).

Here's the cod for one of the tables:

```
$('#ongoingParametersTable').dataTable({
        dom: "lfrti", // paginate = false
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "AjaxHandlerOT",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "pageLength": 99999,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "info": false,
        "scrollY": $('#heightMax1').val(),
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "order": [[3, "desc"]],
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "Id",
                "searchable": false,
                "sortable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, oObj) {
                    return '<a href=\"ReloadTelegram?TeleId=' + oObj[0] + '&TelegramName=' + oObj[2] + '\">Select</a>';
                },
                "width": "5%"
            },
            {
                "name": "FakeId",
                "searchable": false,
                "sortable": false,
                "width": "5%"
            },
            {
                "name": "FormName",
                "width": "7%"
            },
            {
                "name": "FormDate",
                "width": "11%"
            },
            {
                "name": "Telegramme",
                "type": "natural",
                "width": "8%"
            },
            {
                "name": "Train",
                "width": "15%"
            },
            {
                "name": "Agent",
                "width": "19%"
            },
            {
                "name": "Poste",
                "width": "15%"
            },
            {
                "name": "Motive",
                "width": "15%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "url": languageManagement.dataTablesLanguageUrl
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search(val ? val : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });
                column.data().unique().sort(function (a, b) { return DTExtensions.naturalSort(a, b, true) }).each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                });
            });
        }
});
```

I'd appreciate any ideas, I'm pretty desperate at this point. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue (sort of...). I'm posting the answer if someone ever stumbled upon such problem.

First of all, I simply fixed the scrollbar to the table body with:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody { overflow-y: scroll !important;}
```

With this, body of a table was fixed but the header and footer were acting up. Next the solution varied depending on usage of dataTables.

**Ajax data**

In case of data received by ajax call, I called draw() on columns() after creating footer dropdowns (in dataTable options), like this:

```
initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            ...
        }).draw();
    },
```

**Fixed server-side data**

In this case, when dataTables were simply styling existing table, I changed its layout to fixed and manually set column widths. For some reason ajax solution didn't work here.

This is not the most elegant solution but I honestly can't figure out a better one. Let me know if anyone has.